# How do you use an npm package with require & module export as a plain JS library

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms, validation

I'm not sure I'm even asking the right question here, sorry, but I think the two general ones are:

- In what way do you need to modify a node.js package using `require` etc to be used as a plain embedded script/library in HTML?
- How do you call a class constructor (?) in JS as a function to validate a form field?

I'm trying to use this small JS library [NoSwearingPlease](https://github.com/ThreeLetters/NoSwearingPlease) (which is an npm package) in an environment with no node or build system – so I'm just trying to call it like you would jQuery or something with a script & src in the HTML, and then utilise it with a small inline script.

I can see a couple of things are required to get this working:

1. the JSON file needs to be called in a different way (not using require etc)
2. the checker variable needs to be rewritten, again without require

I attempted using jQuery getJSON but I just don't understand the class & scope bits of the library enough to use it I think:

```
var noswearlist = $.getJSON( "./noswearing-swears.json" );
function() {
    console.log( "got swear list from inline script" );
  })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log( "failed to get swear list" );
    })
  noswearlist.done(function() {
    console.log( "done callback as child of noswearlist variable" );
    var checker = new NoSwearing(noswearlist);
    console.log(checker);
});
```

Please halp. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to modify, when outside of node the class is just appended to `window` (global):

```js
fetch("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ThreeLetters/NoSwearingPlease@master/swears.json").then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(data => {
    var noSwearing = new NoSwearing(data);
    console.log(noSwearing.check("squarehead"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ThreeLetters/NoSwearingPlease@master/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Given by the use of jQuery, I have some doubts as to whether the `fetch` API is appropriate. But this is a good solution if he's fine with ES6.

Comment: He do not require use of jQuery, and `fetch` is available on browsers since 2015, so it's not an issue.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't change the fact that some people want to support IE 11 and other old browsers. Disgusting, I know, but it's a valid use case for jQuery and probably the only reason to use it anymore. I assumed that he's using it for that reason, but maybe he's just following a tutorial from 2012. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thank you! This is great and I feel kind of stupid. I had got close to this in my attempts but I think I had some of the JSON syntax wrong. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks @101arrowz – I would like to support IE11  for this project, but it's a nice to have in this case, not essential.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, you can answer this type of question on your own by looking through the source code and looking up things you don't understand. That being said, here's what I was able to gather doing that myself.

For your first question, if you have no build tools you can't use `require`, you have to hope your NPM package supports adding the class to the `window` or has a UMD export (which in this case, it does). If so, you can download the source code or use a CDN like JSDelivr and add a `<script>` tag to link it.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ThreeLetters/NoSwearingPlease@master/index.js"></script>
```

I'm having a hard time deciphering your script (it has a few syntax errors as far as I can tell), so here's what you do if you have a variable `ns` containing the JSON and the string `str` that you need to check:

```js
var checker = new NoSwearing(ns);
checker.check(str);
```

As an aside, you should really use build tools to optimize your bundle size and make using packages a lot easier. And consider dropping jQuery for `document.querySelector`, `fetch`/`XMLHttpRequest`, and other modern JavaScript APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had examined the code and done a lot of looking up, but perhaps I didn't know enough to be looking for the right answers. Unfortunately, the site I'm managing is built in NationBuilder, so as far as I'm aware, there's absolutely no way to integrate build tools.